# Simple app creating Python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I was trying to create a simple app for illustration purposes. The idea is as follows:
Create an application which will run script files associated only to the selected courses (radio buttons). So, I create radio buttons which list out subjects (to click on). Once the subjects are selected the user has to hit the `Enter` button. This should run all the `.py` files for the selected subjects (`execute_script` function).

However, when I run my code, I get 4 messageboxes with 'None' written inside. After clicking ok on them, I get a square windows with only the `enter` button. What can I do to correct this problem?

```
def check(file_name, relStatus):   
    radioValue = relStatus.get()
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('You checked', radioValue)
    been_clicked.append(file_name)   
    return

def execute_script():
    for name in been_cliked:
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:\Users\Max\Subjects\{}'.format(name)])

    yield


def main():

    #Create application
    app = Tk()
    app.title('Coursework')
    app.geometry('450x300+200+200')

    #Header
    labelText = StringVar()
    labelText.set('Select subjects')

    #Dictionary with names
    product_names = {}
    names = []
    file_name = []
    names = ['Math', 'Science', 'English', 'French']
    file_name = ['calc.py', 'physics.py', 'grammar.py', 'livre.py']
    product_names = OrderedDict(zip(names, file_name))

    #Create radio buttons
    global been_clicked
    been_clicked = []
    relStatus = StringVar()
    relStatus.set(None)
    for name,file_name in product_names.iteritems():
        radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text=name, value=name, \
                         variable=relStatus, command=check(file_name, relStatus))

    button = Button(app, text='Click Here', width=20, command=execute_script())
    button.pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)

    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with your script:

1) A typo in your `execute_script()` function: `for name in been_cliked`

2) You are actually *calling* the `check()` function when you create your radio buttons. That's why you're seeing the windows pop up when you run your program.

You need to change this:

```
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text=name, value=name, \
                     variable=relStatus, command=check(file_name, relStatus))
```

to this:

```
radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text=name, value=name, \
                     variable=relStatus, command=check)
```

See how `check` no longer has brackets? That's means you're passing the function name as an argument, instead of actually *calling* the function. Of course, you'll see an immediate problem is that you can no longer pass arguments to your callback function! That's a bigger issue. Here's a couple links to help get you started:

- [How to pass an argument to event handler in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296893/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-event-handler-python-tkinter-programming)
- [How can I pass arguments to Tkinter button's callback command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922621/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-tkinter-buttons-callback-command)

Here is the solution:

Change this:

```
command=check(file_name, reStatus)
```

to this:

```
command = lambda: check(file_name, relStatus)
```

3) You don't actually `pack()` your radio buttons anywhere. Add something like this just after you create your radio buttons in your `for` loop: `radio1.pack(side='top')`

4) You have the same problem with your callback for your `Click Here` button. You need to change your command to not call the function, but just refer to it: `command = execute_script`

5) In `execute_script()`, make sure you `import subprocessing`

6) Are you sure you want `yield` instead of `return` in your `execute_script()` function?

7) In all your functions, you need to make sure that `been_clicked` is global.

I think if you fix these issues you'll be closer to getting what you're looking for. Good luck.!

Comment: Strange that the `for name in been_cliked` problem doesn't result in a `NameError: global name 'been_cliked' is not defined` error since the `, command=execute_script()` is _calling_ `execute_script`.

Comment: I agree. The reason is he has `yield` instead of `return`. Using `yield` won't cause `NameError` to be raised. Not sure why that is though.

Comment: Ah, the answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

`yield` causes a generator to be returned, but until that generated is used, the code hasn't been run yet.

Comment: Indeed...mystery explained. To save folks the trouble of looking it up, here's the key paragraph about generator functions from @e-satis, et al's excellent answer: "To master yield, you must understand that **when you call the function, the code you have written in the function body does not run.** The function only returns the generator object, this is a bit tricky :-)"